# How to check whether the table has been created and how to get the values from a radiobutton and a spinner using SQlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm Developing an android app in which there are Login activity and a Questionnaire activity contains Questions which as radio Buttons and also a Button(Next).So now I wanted to create a database to store the values of the respective fields. I've typed the  code  for dataHandler and Login.java now the problem is i wanted to know whether the table has been created and also how to view my table please help  me and also please check whether my code is correct.
Thanks in Advance.

[image: Here is my Login activity's graphical representation]

Here is code for the DatabaseAdapter.java

```
public class DatabaseAdapter  {
 DatabaseHandler dbhandler;

 public DatabaseAdapter(Context context){
     dbhandler =new DatabaseHandler(context);

 }
public long insertData(String name,String desig,String years,String dept)
  {
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbhandler.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
     content.put(DatabaseHandler.NAME, name);
     content.put(DatabaseHandler.DESIGNATION,desig);
     content.put(DatabaseHandler.YEARS, years);
     content.put(DatabaseHandler.DEPARTMENT, dept);
     long  id=db.insertOrThrow(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_NAME, null, content);
     return id;
  }

static class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final String NAME="name";
  private static final String DESIGNATION="desig";
  private static final String YEARS="years";
  private static final String DEPARTMENT="dept";
  private static final String TABLE_NAME="visteon";
  private static final String DATA_BASE_NAME="VisteonSurvey";
  private static final  int DATABASE_VERSION=2;
  private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+NAME+" VARCHAR(255),"+DESIGNATION+"text not null,"+YEARS+" text not null,"+DEPARTMENT+" text not null);";

 public DatabaseHandler(Context context)
 {
    super(context,DATA_BASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

 }
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try{
             db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         try {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS visteon");
             onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is code for Login.java

```
public void OnClickListener(View v)
{
  name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  years1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
  years2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
  years3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
  manager=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
  teamleader=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
  rg1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Designation);
  rg2=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Years);
  dept=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  proceed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (validationSuccess()) 
            {
                if(manager.isChecked())
                {
                    Intent managerIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManagerQuestionnaire1.class); // <----- START "SEARCH" ACTIVITY
                    startActivityForResult(managerIntent, 0);
                }
                else 
                      {
                      Intent teamleaderIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeamleaderQuestionnaire1.class); // <----- START "TYPE ENTRIES OUT" ACTIVITY
                      startActivityForResult(teamleaderIntent, 0);
                }

            }   
            else {
              AlertDialog();
               }
            String user=name.getText().toString();
            String designation=rg1.getContext().toString();
            String experience=rg2.getContext().toString();
            String department=dept.getContext().toString();

            long id= DatabaseHandler.insertData (user, designation, experience, department);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Form Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
  });
```

Comment: if you run your code on emulator then you can copy your database from path data/data/your app name/database/...
you can also see created table and values in it.

Comment: you should have Sqlite Databse browser to see your database

Comment: @jyomin  can u please provide me the link to download the SQlite Database browser.

Comment: @Umang I also checked  in the file explorer data/data/ but im not able to find my app and database.

Comment: @jyomin can you please check whether my code is correct and have I got the values of radiobutton and spinner properly.

Comment: @steve check in file explorer on this path : **//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>** if database is created then it must be there.